# Adding html code from subfunction via strings

Tags: perl

I have 2 functions that generates simple HTML output

```
  sub one_data {} 

  sub generate_page {}
```

The generate_page is the 'meat and potatoes' which generates all of the content, however the one_data{} function generates a small amount of html (divs, etc)

I am trying to add it to a section of code that generate_page does, something like this, ie:

```
$npage .= sprintf "<div class=sidepage>%s</div>", &one_data();
```

That doesn't seem to accomplish what I'm doing even though one_data is a simple string (in theory it should work per perldoc sprintf.

I've also tried this, ie:

```
my $data = &one_data();
$npage .= sprintf "<div class=whatever>%s</div>", $data;
```

But the format modifier "%s" only contains the number 1 at all times.

One_data /does/ work, as I've moved it into a simple perl script and it displays the required html output.

Comment: Does `one_data` return a string ? I guess it is just printing.

Comment: make sure `one_data()` **returns** data and doesn't print it

Comment: It does return data if I call it separately in a function that runs it as standalone.

Comment: Unrelated, you need not use the `&` glyph to introduce a simple function call; that's an idiom from IIRC the pre-Perl 5 days, and thus now many years out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Your `one_data` sub should use an explicit [return](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) statement:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $npage .= sprintf "<div class=sidepage>%s</div>", one_data();
print "$npage\n";

sub one_data {
    return 'foooo';
}
```

Outputs:

```
<div class=sidepage>foooo</div>
```

If your sub uses `print` instead of `return`, the value returned by the sub will be `1` (assuming the `print` was successful).  See also `perldoc perlsub`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I fixed this earlier. Seems the data I was parsing was timing out too quickly and it wasn't added the requested data, so I had to add a sleep command to fetch it in a manner.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed this by adding an artificial sleep into the function, as it was returning too early/timing out.